# Change post-GRUB, pre-Plymouth boot font size

Tags: boot, fonts

QFHD on my Dell XPS13's 13.3" display is hard to read sometimes. I've fixed GRUB and Plymouth, but between those the text is still hard to read, see [here](https://twitter.com/ctimmerman17/status/1229501683861987328). According to that and `sudo less /var/log/boot.log` it appears to be before `Show Plymouth Boot Screen`.
How to make that text more readable during boot?

[image: Tiny text after GRUB but before larger Plymouth text]
[image: boot.log at time of above image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite 1024×576 being very compatible according to `xrandr`, 1280x720 appears to be the lowest 16:9 resolution that works:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=1280x720"
$ sudo update-grub
$ reboot
```

That also affects the virtual consoles, however, so now i'll have to  undo the larger font i set for those using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` or set the VIDEOMODE in `/etc/default/console-setup`.